# How to update model in ui-codemirror

Tags: angularjs

I have two separate controllers which shared a property. If the first controller changes the property the second controller should recognize it and should change the text in the codemirror text area. I tried to figure it out in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g7sh76wm/9/) example but I could not find a solution.

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.codemirror']);

app.service('sharedProperties', function() {
    var objectValue = {
        data: 'test object value'
    };

    return {
        setText: function(value) {
            objectValue.data = value;
        },
        getText: function() {
            return objectValue;
        }
    }
});

app.controller('myController1', function($scope, $timeout, sharedProperties) {
    $scope.setText = function(text){
        sharedProperties.setText(text);
      console.log(sharedProperties.getText().data);
    }

});

app.controller('myController2', function($scope, sharedProperties) {
    $scope.editorOptions = {
            lineWrapping: true,
            lineNumbers: true,
            readOnly: 'nocursor',
            mode: 'xml'
        };
        $scope.mappingFile = sharedProperties.getText();
                console.log($scope.mappingFile);
});
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController1">
        <input type="text" ng-model="newText"></input>
        <button ng-click="setText(newText)">Set Text</button><br/>
    </div>    
    <div ng-controller="myController2">
       <ui-codemirror ui-codemirror-opts="editorOptions" ng-model="mappingFile.data" ui-refresh="true"></ui-codemirror>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, the way that you're doing you have 2 controllers in the same page but without any relation, I'd suggest you to make one of them *as* child of another.

So, to achieve what you want you need do a kind of `watch` on that variable from the *parent* controller.

**Steps:**

1. Use the `$broadcast` to send `data` to the *child* `controller`

```
$scope.$broadcast('newText', $scope.newText);
```

2. Use `$on` to receive the `data` from the *parent* `controller`:

```
$scope.$on('newText', function(event, text) {
  ...
});
```

Here's the `code` working based on your original `code`:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('myApp', ['ui.codemirror'])
    .controller('myController1', myController1)
    .controller('myController2', myController2);

  myController1.$inject = ['$scope', '$timeout'];

  function myController1($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.setText = function(text) {
      console.log('Sent...', $scope.newText);
      $scope.$broadcast('newText', $scope.newText);          
    }
  }

  myController2.$inject = ['$scope'];

  function myController2($scope) {
    $scope.editorOptions = {
      lineWrapping: true,
      lineNumbers: true,
      readOnly: 'nocursor',
      mode: 'xml'
    };
    
    $scope.$on('newText', function(event, text) {
      if (!text) return;
      $scope.mappingFile = text;
      console.log('Received... ', $scope.mappingFile);
    });
  }
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.17.0/codemirror.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-codemirror/master/src/ui-codemirror.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController1">
      <input type="text" ng-model="newText">
      <button ng-click="setText()">Set Text</button>
      <hr>
      <div ng-controller="myController2">
        <textarea ui-codemirror-opts="editorOptions" ng-model="mappingFile"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Some **notes**:

1. You don't need to pass `ngModel` as *parameter* in your `ngClick`, you can access it directly in your controller simply calling `$scope.newText` (as I did);
2. `<input>` is a *self-closing* *tag*, so of course, you don't need to close it.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thx for your nice solution. Is there the possibility to have this kind of `watch` on the `sharedProperty.getText()`. So that the second controller don't has come into the first controller?

Comment: Well, in my opinion it's the best approach.. another is to use `$rootScope`, but I prefer this.